# JSSOR Slider - responsive mode - combine width AND height limit

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, slider, jssor

Trying to make JSSOR Slider work on mobile devices, in both portrait AND landscape mode.

Problem: the "Scale to: window height" option works for landscape, but it's too tall for portrait. The "Scale to: window width" option works for portrait, but it's too wide for landscape.

How can these 2 code sections be combined, to make the slider fit:

- Parent container **width** when in **portrait** mode
- Parent container **height** when in **landscape** mode

Responsive code for "parent-container-width":

```
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

Responsive code for "parent-container-height":

```
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;
            if (refSize) {
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleHeight(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

I'm sure this is easy for anyone who's familiar with JS, but my knowledge is sadly lacking.

P.S. Ideally, if it's possible to scale, in landscape mode, just the **main image** to the height of the screen, leaving the thumbnails and bullets below the edge of the screen (don't really need them on mobile, the user can swipe left/right), I would love to see that solution as well.

Comment: Trying to set the dimensions of either the parent container, or the #jssor_1 div, via CSS, fails miserably, since the Javascript overrides whatever is set initially. I.e. it works right up to the moment any screen dimensions change = fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in the 'examples/full-screen-contain-in-window.html'

```
//responsive code begin
//remove responsive code if you don't want the slider to scale while window scaling
function ScaleSlider() {
    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var windowWidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;

    if (windowWidth) {
        var windowHeight = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;

        var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
        var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

        if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(windowWidth);

            var scaleHeight = jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight();
            $Jssor$.$Css(wrapperElement, "marginTop", ((windowHeight - scaleHeight) / 2) + "px");
        }
        else {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(windowHeight);
            $Jssor$.$Css(wrapperElement, "marginTop", "0px");
        }
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();

$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Comment: That somehow made it even worse. Now it's not even fitting into the portrait window.

Comment: Does `examples/full-screen-contain-in-window.html` work for your case? you can get it here https://github.com/jssor/slider